# How to force ssl in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I already have this .htaccess file in a platform i am working on, we have an ssl certificate installed and we want all the site to use https, how can this be done without affecting other rules

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

Options -Indexes
```

I saw some code for doing that on some answers here and other sites, but i didn't know where to add it and how it will affect the site, the site is live and can't be messed with,

thank you all for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: i just noticed, it doesn't allow access to direct files! any idea why please?

Comment: What do you mean by that, provide some example.

Comment: like domain.com/folder/file.php is running the index rule even though the actual file file.php exists

Comment: This rule blocks all real files and directories using 3 conditions. Do you a htaccess in folder also?